# Forms on a Slope—Contractor wants more money to reinforce them after a rainy week

Tags: concrete, contractors, weather

We are having a patio poured on a slope. The forms are complete and have been sitting for two weeks. Over the time period, it has rained here just under an inch. We are in the Texas Hill Country, so the patio is on limestone rock and caliche soil. The contractor is asking for additional money (above the contract price) because he says it will take four men 8 hours to reinforce the forms because the rain will have compromised the structure somehow.
Please advise. We are fair people on a fixed income and want to do the right thing for folks working hard for us, but money is tight, and we can’t spend needlessly. Although retired, I worked a year to pay for this patio.
Thank you.

Comment: What *exactly* did you contract this contractor to do? Just to do the forms (and other contractors or you are doing the rest of the patio), or for the entire finished patio job? If the contract is for the entire job, they probably have no right to charge extra (if it's not your fault the forms have been sitting unfilled for weeks). But if they refuse to proceed, you might need a local lawyer to read the contract and send a sternly-worded letter.

Comment: An inch of rain over two weeks does not seem that bad, much different if an inch in hour.  Pictures of the forms might help.  A local contractor should know local conditions and build right the first time.  Rain usually is expected to happen sometime.

Comment: What is the reason for the delay? If you told them "I'll be out of town for two weeks, finish when I get back" then it may legitimately be on you. But if you gave them no reason to delay and they delayed for their own reasons (material or labor issues or delayed because of the rain) *and* rain is not unusual this time of year, then it is on them - i.e., they should have built the forms to handle potential rain and/or protected them from the rain. If significant rain is *extremely* unusual this time of year then they may have a legitimate reason to ask for more money.